# What is the cap for equipment modifiers?

Tags: diablo-iii

When judging equipment, whether a drop or in the Auction house, it's often best to know how far the item is from being "optimal." For example, a +intelligence +vitality ring may have +40 of each, but the cap for the modifier at the level of the ring may allow for up to +65 of each.

Is there a table or list of these caps? Level 60 stat modifiers would be good, but a list of modifiers by level would be excellent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A couple of good off-site resources for affix ranges:

http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41045-spoiler-diablo-iii-item-affixes/

http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?816871-List-of-all-Affixes-with-Stats

Incgamers also has a [**very nice chart**](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/item-affix-quick-look-chart) to show the maximum affix value possible on equipment and the total maximum that you can get. *Some comments indicate the data might be inaccurate, but it will serve well to get a general idea.*

**Note:** When this answer was last updated, neither of them were accurate for IAS values (which were changed in 1.0.3). Also, the Diablofans version which I used to make the list below has some incorrect values such as for CritChance, so ymmv on the accuracy of other entries :(.

From a look at the Diablofans list, some of the maximum value caps for the various modifiers are listed below.

- 41-50% More Damage
- Weapon Minimum Damage 27-32%
- Weapon Maximum Damage 27-32%
- Min Weapon Damage by 143-256 and Max Weapon Damage by 191-381
- Reflects 1713-2544 Damage Back to the attacker
- Adds 361-397 to Armor
- 5-6% Damage Reduction vs. Ranged
- 5-6% Damage Reduction vs. Melee
- Gives 658-959 Life on Hit
- Gives 239-479 Life on Hit (Ring)
- Gives 1972-2878 Life for each Kill
- Gives 985-1439 Life for each Kill (Ring)
- Chance to (Chill/Slow/Stun/Immobilize/Freeze/Knockback) Target on Hit

  - 1-2.59% (1h & offhands)
  - 1-5% (2h, and one specific armor piece per type of effect)
- Additional Chance to Block

  - 9% (Shield)
  - 15% (Amulet)
- Increased Chance for Critical Hit

  - 10-12% (Ring, Bracers, Helm)
  - 18-19% (Amulet, Gloves, Offhand)
- Increase Critical Strike Damage by

  - 66-100% (Weapon, Amulet)
  - 35-50% (Ring, Gloves)
- Increase Max Life by

  - 10-12%
  - 15-16% (Amulet, Shield)
- Increases Movement Speed by 12%
- Increases Life Regeneration by

  - 411-599 per Second (Amulet, Chest armor)
  - 235-341 per Second (Armor, Offhand, Ring)
- Provides (Specific) Resistance of 51-60
- Provides 71-80 Resistance to All Damage Types (Amulet, Ring, Shield)
- Increases (Str, Dex, Int, Vit) by

  - 170-200 (Amulet, Belt, Shoulder, Weapon)
  - 90-100 (Ring, Armor, Offhand)
- Increases a combination of 2 primary attributes (e.g. Int & Vit) by

  - 45-150 (Amulet, Weapon)
  - 30-100 (Ring, Armor, Offhand)
- 143-667 (element other than cold) Damage
- 96-399 Cold Damage

Comment: Could you add the contents of that post to your answer? If the forum is moved, restructured, etc. this question would become answerless real quick.

Comment: @Hyppy: I will try to search for a better organized list and maybe post part of it - but the entire list is a bit too big to include in a single comment imho.

Comment: Please leave this as a link. SE doesn't need to be a info dump.

Comment: @MattJoiner I agree that it isn't worth repeating all info here, but I have added a brief summary so people can get a general idea of the max values - I recommend reading the links for detailed info.

Comment: Perfect, thanks :-) I disagree with Matt, however, since information is generally better to keep in the answer instead of in a link that may or may not still be around in the future

Comment: Probably should update this with the new maxes for two-handed items from patch 1.04