# What the best bonuses for each item type in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the cap for equipment modifiers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70529/what-is-the-cap-for-equipment-modifiers)

Different items have different bonuses available, with different ranges in Diablo 3. What are the ranges for level 60+ items, and subsequently, what are the best bonuses to aim for with each item type?

Please link to a good reference if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete list with the maximum possible affixes on items is listed and updated at:

http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/item-affix-quick-look-chart

Comment: Cheers this is the table I've been using.

Comment: Is there an updated version of this table for 1.0.7?